# How to verify text in a spinner/loader?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am trying to capture and verify the text which appears in a spinner after clicking on a link. Is it possible to perform this type of test in Katalon?

I created the following keyword:

```
@Keyword
    def activitySpinner(){

        def activSpinner = WebUI.getText(findTestObject('Object Repository/WMS/Page_Dashboard/div_System Activity Loading Please Wait )'))
        return activSpinner
    }
```

Then I tried the following script to use the keyword:

```
def actSpinner = CustomKeywords.'com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.activitySpinner'()

if (WebUI.verifyMatch(actSpinner, 'System Activity Loading... Please Wait :).*', true, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)){
    println("The spinner shows the text: " + actSpinner)
}
```

The DOM shows the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.150.2.43:10093/js/jquery/jquery.page.1562162263.js"></script>
```

When I right click and open the above, I see the following for that particular link:

```
$j(document).on("click", "#system_activity", function() {
            showLoader('System Activity Loading...');
            window.location=BASE_URL + "erp/wms/statistics";
```

The “Please Wait :)” part was shown here on the page:

```
function showLoader(msgText,visible){

            if(typeof(msgText)==='undefined') msgText = "Loading...";
            var theme = "a",
            textVisible = true,
            textonly = false;
            html = "";
            msgText = msgText + ' Please Wait :)';
            if(typeof(visible)==='undefined'){
                $j.mobile.loading( 'show', {
                    text: msgText,
                    textVisible: textVisible,
                    theme: theme,
                    textonly: textonly,
                    html: html
                });
            }else{
                $j.mobile.loading( 'hide' );
            }
```

The spinner shows the text "System Activity Loading... Please Wait :)" and this is what I need to verify in Katalon Studio but get the following error after running the script:

```
09-12-2019 10:55:07 AM Test Cases/regression/WMS/C16320 - Activity Module

Elapsed time: 1m - 4.408s

com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.activitySpinner:92

com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.invokeMethod:0

Test Cases/regression/WMS/C16320 - Activity Module FAILED.
Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to get text of object 'Object Repository/WMS/Page_Dashboard/div_System Activity Loading Please Wait )'
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.GetTextKeyword.getText(GetTextKeyword.groovy:88)
com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1568303703564.run(TempTestCase1568303703564.groovy:21)
Caused by: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: 'Object Repository/WMS/Page_Dashboard/div_System Activity Loading Please Wait )' located by 'By.xpath: //*[(text() = 'System Activity Loading... Please Wait :)' or . = 'System Activity Loading... Please Wait :)')]' not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException` exception that basically says the element isn't in the DOM at that moment. Maybe it hasn't loaded yet.

First, since I'm not sure `findTestObject('Object Repository/WMS/Page_Dashboard/div_System Activity Loading Please Wait )')` is correctly defines the element, so let's change that with the following:

```
TestObject spinner = new TestObject().addProperty("css", ConditionType.EQUALS, ".ui-icon-loading")
```

Next is to try adding a wait condition (wait 30 seconds for the element to appear) before getting the element text. Combination of both would result in something like

```
@Keyword
def activitySpinner(){
    WebUI.waitForElementVisible(spinner, 30)
    def activSpinner = WebUI.getText(spinner)
    return activSpinner
}
```

Katalon docs for the [WebUI.waitForElementVisible()](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-wait-for-element-visible.html#description).

Comment: I tried the above code and got the same error about "unable to get text of object". Does the waitForElementVisible need to be placed in the script instead of the keyword since the spinner appears after clicking on a link?

Comment: You can put the wait in the script as well. Are you sure the element is there when trying to manually run the script? It is also possible the element is inside of an iframe that opens after clicking the link.

Comment: I put the wait in the script also and got the same error. Does it have to be put in the beginning of the script before referencing the Custom Keywords? The element is there when trying to manually run the script. There is something called "bgiframe: true" which I think is different from an iframe but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can put the wait condition just before interacting with the element. Also, if that is an iframe, add [WebUI.switchToFrame()](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-switch-to-frame.html) command before the wait. If you want more detail, you will need to share the HTML of the page in question.

Comment: I confirmed that there was no iframe on the page. I shared some of the HTML code above so I am not sure how much more code you would like to see. Let me know and I will share it.

Comment: Also, could you tell me how to put the wait condition before interacting with the element? In the script, I have this code   
`WebUI.waitForElementVisible(findTestObject('Object Repository/WMS/Page_Dashboard/div_System Activity Loading Please Wait )'), 30)  def actSpinner = CustomKeywords.'com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.activitySpinner'() def sysText = CustomKeywords.'com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.activityText'()if (actSpinner == 'System Activity Loading... Please Wait :)') { println("Activity spinner has the text: " + actSpinner) }`  Is that right?

Comment: That looks ok. The problem is the DOM, you posted only the script tab, what does the DOM look like at the moment of the attempted interaction with the loader? I have a suspicion that your xpath might be off.

Comment: It is very tricky to get the DOM info once the spinner starts loading. Before clicking the link and the loading of the spinner, it shows the following:  `//div[@class='ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default']` and `//span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading']` underneath. Once the spinner starts loading, it shows:  `//div[@class='ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-verbose']` with nothing underneath.

Comment: Both should work, but without the html of the DOM it is really hard to say anything more.

Comment: So how would you like me to send the DOM? It can be a huge file and I am not sure if it can be attached in the comments. Even copying pasting will take a lot of space.

Comment: I don't need the whole DOM, but just the relevant part (say, 3 or 4 levels deep) around the spinner/loader element.

Comment: This is what I got:

<!-- Hidden Variables -->
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_factory" value="834">
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_factory_db" value="CFFGRP">

<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  var MAGE_STORE_ID = 'tamco';
  //]]>
</script><div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading"></span><h1>loading</h1></div></div>

</body>  Let me know if that's enough or you need something else.

Comment: I looked at the answer and came up with the following:  
@Keyword
def activitySpinner(){
    TestObject spinner = new TestObject().addProperty("css", ConditionType.EQUALS, ".ui-icon-loading")
    WebUI.waitForElementVisible(spinner, 30)
    def activSpinner = WebUI.getText(spinner)
    return activSpinner
}

Ran the script and got error:  
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ConditionType for class: com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords
at com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.activitySpinner(ModuleKeywords.groovy:109) Is something wrong with the order of code?

Comment: You will need to import the following: `import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType` at the top of your script.

Comment: Now I am getting this error
```
09-26-2019 09:55:35 AM Test Cases/C16320 - Activity Module
Elapsed time: 1m - 7.722s
com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.activitySpinner:111
com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.invokeMethod:0
Test Cases/C16320 - Activity Module FAILED.
Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to wait for object '' to be visible at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed( 
WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
``` 
I tried increasing the wait from 30 to 40 but still got the same error.

Comment: I changed the selector to "h1:nth-child(2)" instead of ".ui-icon-loading" and got only one word instead of the full text of the spinner```6: if (verifyTextPresent(actSpinner, true, STOP_ON_FAILURE))
2019-09-26 12:12:43.902 DEBUG testcase.C16320 - Activity Module - 1: println("The spinner shows the text: " + actSpinner)
The spinner shows the text: Activity``` Do you know why it is not capturing the whole text?

Comment: Again, I cannot answer this without the DOM. Bear in mind that the DOM changes dynamically so only way to answer that is to inspect the DOM in the moment of the test execution.